# Show that $\|T^n\|=\frac{1}{n!}$ for $(Tf)(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt, f\in C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ and define,
$$ (T f )(x) =\int_0^x f (t) dt, \ x ∈ [0, 1]$$
for $f ∈ C[0, 1]$. Show that $\|T^n\|=\frac{1}{n!}$

---

By definition, I know that $\|T\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|Tf(x)\|$, using the norm of $C[0,1]$, we have that
$$\begin{aligned}
\|T\| &= \left\Vert\int_0^x f(t)dt\right\Vert \\
&\leq \int_0^x \|f(t)\|dt =t \\ &\leq 1
\end{aligned}$$

And since I can find a function whose norm is 1 (any function such that $f(x)=1$, for some $x\in[0,1]$). I know that
$$\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|(Tf)(x)\|=1$$
(Couldn't find a more elegant way to conclude that).

I suppose then I'll have to use an induction argument, however, I'm struggling finding a way to prove it for another $n$. I'll have that,
$$\|T^2f\|=\left\Vert\int_0^t\int_0^tf(t)dt\right\Vert$$
But I'm concluding this is one again by the same arguments I had for $T$. What am I not seeing?

Comment: Cant you just continue the same argument: $||\int_0^t \int_0^x f(t) dt dx || \leq \int_0^t \int_0^x ||f(t)|| dt dx \leq \int_0^t x dx \leq x^2/2! \leq 1/2!$. Now come up with an example for equality which is $f(t) = 1$ !? Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- Show by induction that for all $n\geq 0$ and all $x\in[0,1]$, $|(T^nf)(x)|\leq\frac{x^n}{n!}\|f\|$. What does this tell you about $\|T^n\|$?
- Let $f_0=1$ be the constant function with value $1$, and use induction to compute $T^n(f_0)$ for each for each $n\geq 0$. Therefore…